# How to remove all attributes of a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried:

```
match (n:MyNode) remove n.*
```

but that doesn't work.  the context: I want to essentially redefine the node with new data but rather than deleting it (which means I'd have to delete all links to it too) and creating it again, I want to just remove the attributes and set my new values.  I don't want to just set the new values because attributes no longer used should be removed

incidentally, I know I can get the properties of a node via the `keys` function but I can't figure out how to use it for my purposes:

```
match (n:MyNode) remove keys(n)
match (n:MyNode) remove n[keys(n)]
```

not sure how to dereference the array returned to remove the attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n:MyNode)
SET n = {};
```

The `SET n = $map` syntax replaces all existing properties with the properties in the map. Since the query uses an empty map, the end result is that all properties are deleted.